# Using XMLTransformer.transformXLS but not able to retain the formatting in xls template to the produced xls file

Tags: java, xml, excel, templates

```
synchronized public void transform(
    TransformationContext<Map<String, Object>> context,
    OutputStream o) throws ServiceException{
  BufferedInputStream templateInputStream = null;

  String classPathLocation = !context.getType().getTemplate().startsWith("/")
      ? "/" + context.getType().getTemplate() 
      : context.getType().getTemplate();

  URL templateURL = ClassLoader.class.getResource(classPathLocation);

  templateInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(templateURL.openStream());

  Workbook workbook = xlsTransformer.transformXLS(templateInputStream, context.getContext());
  workbook.write(o);

  templateInputStream.close();
  o.flush();
  o.close();
}
```

**From OP's comment :-**

I have a certain xls which i m using as a template and i Am trying to generate another excel using that template.. but the generated template is coming in some foriegn language which is may be a unicode problem and also the font and formatting of template is not retained

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `<xsl:preserve-space> <xsl:strip-space>` tags? Instead of using the whitespace/text for output you could opt for explicit output by tag.

Comment: I have a certain xls which i m using as a template and i Am trying to generate another excel using that template.. but the generated template is coming in some foriegn language which is may be a unicode problem and also the font and formatting of template is not retained